# Flask-SQLAlchemy query where substring is in database against a whole string

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask-sqlalchemy

For the impatient, I am looking for a way to execute this query:
`SELECT * FROM area WHERE '125122141113166' LIKE CONCAT(area.code, '%') ORDER BY LENGTH(area.code) DESC` from an Flask-SQLAlchemy model.

Here's more information on the setup:
I have the following table (irrelevant fields discarded):

```
+----------------------------------+
|code|location                     |
+==================================+
|12  |startupzone2                 |
+----------------------------------+
|123 |startupzone2subzone3         |
+----------------------------------+
|1234|startupzone2subzone3building4|
+----------------------------------+
|126 |startupzone2subzone6         |
+----------------------------------+
|1287|startupzone2subzone8building7|
+----------------------------------+
```

I want to be able to find the location by the code, but the search string provided is in the format "125122141113166". I can use the query in the beginning in order to retrieve the most relevant location, but i'd like to use the ORM for that (if possible). So far I've read that I can use `match ... against ...` with a fulltext index, however I got an error when I tried making a fulltext index on the table.
Currently I'm using the query above to extract the primary key from the table and use `Area.query.get(pkey)` to get an object, but I am looking for a better way to do it, if one exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't determine whether Flask-SQLAlchemy or SQLAlchemy provide the means to do this, I added the following static method to my class:

```
@staticmethod
def match(location):
    query = "SELECT id FROM rate WHERE {0} LIKE CONCAT(area.code, '%%')  ORDER BY LENGTH(area.code) DESC LIMIT 1".format(location)
    try:
        res = db.engine.execute(query).first()
        return None if not res else Area.query.get(res[0])
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print "Unable to get location for for location code {0}, reason: {1}".format(location, str(e))
    return None
```

and I'm able to use it as Area.match(location) which is not the best but sufficient for my needs.